# How do I verify the number of invocations of overloaded method using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, overloading, powermockito

How do I check if `bar(Alpha, Baz)` called `bar(Xray, Baz)` using Mockito - without actually calling the later, given my MCVE class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    public String bar(Xray xray, Baz baz) {
        return "Xray";
    }

    public String bar(Zulu zulu, Baz baz) {
        return "Zulu";
    }

    public String bar(Alpha alpha, Baz baz) {
        if(alpha.get() instanceof Xray) {
            return bar((Xray)alpha.get(), baz);
        } else if(alpha.get() instanceof Zulu) {
            return bar((Zulu)alpha.get(), baz);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I have roughly the following Mockito-enhanced JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() {
    Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
    Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
    alpha.set(new Xray());

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo stub = spy(foo); // Spying on Foo, as I want to call the real bar(Alpha, Baz)
    // Preventing bar(Xray, Baz) from being called by providing behavior/stub
    when(stub.bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class))).thenReturn("ok");
    // Calling the real "parent" method
    stub.bar(alpha, baz);
    // Testing if bar(Xray, Baz) was called by bar(Alpha, Baz)
    verify(stub, times(1)).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
}
```

And it fails:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations:
foo.bar(
    <any>,
    <any> ); 
Wanted 1 time:
-> at FooTest.testBar_callsBarWithXray(FooTest.java:14) 
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at FooTest.testBar_callsBarWithXray(FooTest.java:12)
```

I suppose it's because `any(Class.class)` matches anything, and doesn't do type checking... So, from Mockito's point of view, I'm really calling `bar()` twice: in `Foo` and in `FooTest` (on line 12).

What do I have to do to make the test do what I actually want: ensure `bar(Xray, Baz)` was called when I call `bar(Alpha, baz)` (while at the same time intercepting the call to `bar(Xray, Baz)`)?

Using the `eq()` Matcher (`when(stub.bar(eq(Xray.class), any(Baz.class))...`) causes a compilation error, `Cannot resolve method 'bar(Class<Xray>, Baz)'` - but then, I probably shouldn't use it that way anyway (`eq(xray)` would probably be more like it)...

Also, on a related note, if I try to make the overloads of `bar(Alpha, Baz)` `private`, I get a compilation error for `FooTest`, stating:

> Error:(10, 12) java: bar(Xray,Baz) has private access in Foo

Is there a way to get round that using PowerMockito? How?
(Obviously, I only want to count the calls to `bar(Xray, Baz)` - counting all calls to all overloads of `bar()` is out of the question...)

Just using `eq(xray)` instead of `any(Xray.class)` on lines 10 and 14 of the test does the trick - but I'm not really interested in *what* (specific) Xray object is passed in as an argument to `bar()`, as long as it's *any* `Xray` object...

Update: I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32208501/2018047) for the "PowerMockito and `private` methods" part of the discussion, and figured out how to make this work for `public` methods; cf. my [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206315/how-do-i-verify-the-number-of-invocations-of-overloaded-method-using-mockito#comment52298780_32206315).

Comment: I've got a minimal example which stubs out `Alpha` to contain a method `get` and `set` which *passes* your tests.  Could you include more code that we could see so that we too can run your *exact* case?

Comment: Murphy's law, I guess... My example above is actually working for me too, now that I try it -even though I can't spot a difference. Sorry about that. Anyhow, when I set breakpoints and stepped through the real thing, I got another error message: "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue... A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies with doReturn family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method." Sure enough, `doReturn("ok").when(stub).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class))` makes it pass. Don't ask me why, though - I have no idea...

Answer (score 2):

#### You don't need to do this.

The reason this is driving you nuts is that you aren't using Mockito the way it is intended to be used. It *can* be used this way, but it should not be.

You don't need to test that the right method was called, you need to test that the **behavior of your class is correct**. What does that mean?

1. You want to check that `"Xray"` was returned.

   ```
   String result = foo.bar(alpha, baz);
   assertEquals("Xray", result);
   ```
2. You want to check that `Alpha.get` was called. If anything, this means that `Alpha` should be the stub, not `Foo`.

   ```
   Alpha alpha = spy(new Alpha());
   String result = foo.bar(alpha, baz);
   verify(alpha).get();
   ```

The bottom line is this: You have your System Under Test, in this case `Foo`. That class should be a **real class**. **Your mocks and stubs should be the other objects that interact with `Foo`**; verify that the interactions *do the correct things*.

In other words, you shouldn't be testing *how* `Foo` works, you should be testing *that* `Foo` does what it's supposed to do; that the results are correct.

Comment: We are currently refactoring about as much as we are writing new code at the moment, and I didn't want to have to rewrite tests all the time - hence me trying to test the smallest unit: methods (instead of classes). But I do appreciate your point... ;-)

Comment: @Christian But my answer *does* test a method... it tests that `bar` does the right thing...