# PowerMockito throws NullPointerException when trying to stub private overloaded method

Tags: java, powermock, overloading, private-members, powermockito

I'm (still) trying to check if `bar(Alpha, Baz)` called `bar(Xray, Baz)` using PowerMockito (as `bar(Xray, Baz)` is `private`) - without actually calling the later, given my MCVE class `Foo` below. (I went through the same class [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32206315/2018047), with all methods in `Foo` being `public` - in case you've got a déjà vu...)

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar(Xray xray, Baz baz) {
        return "Xray";
    }

    private String bar(Zulu zulu, Baz baz) {
        return "Zulu";
    }

    public String bar(Alpha alpha, Baz baz) {
        if(alpha.get() instanceof Xray) {
            return bar((Xray)alpha.get(), baz);
        } else if(alpha.get() instanceof Zulu) {
            return bar((Zulu)alpha.get(), baz);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test below, I get a NPE from PowerMock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// @PrepareOnlyThisForTest(Foo.class) // we aren't looking at the byte code, I think
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() throws Exception {
        Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
        Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
        alpha.set(new Xray());

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo stub = spy(foo); // using Mockito, as it's neither final nor "not spyable"

        // NPE at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:67)
        PowerMockito.doReturn("ok").when(stub, "bar", Xray.class, Baz.class);

        stub.bar(alpha, baz);
        // Testing if bar(Xray, Baz) was called by bar(Alpha, Baz)
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(foo).invoke("bar", Xray.class, Baz.class);
        // Mockito's equivalent for a public method: verify(stub, times(1)).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
    }
}
```

If I make the stub a `PowerMockito.spy(foo)`, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)` instead. (It's bubbling up on the same line as the NPE.)

I'm using Mockito-core 1.9.5, PowerMock 1.5.4 (module-junit4 and api-mockito) and JUnit 4.11.

What do I need to change to stop the exceptions from being thrown? How can I make this test work? (Other than [testing *that*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206838/2018047) my class works, instead of *how*... ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

When setting the expectations, we have to use the exact argument matcher. In your case, it is
Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class)

I have modified your code as below and also added assert statement on output object of your test method.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareOnlyThisForTest(Foo.class) // we aren't looking at the byte code, I think
 public class FooTest {

   @Test
   public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() throws Exception {
       Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
       Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
       alpha.set(new Xray());

       Foo foo = new Foo();
       Foo stub = PowerMockito.spy(foo); // using Mockito, as it's neither final nor "not spyable"

      // NPE at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:67)
      PowerMockito.doReturn("ok").when(stub, "bar", Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));

      String res = stub.bar(alpha, baz);
      Assert.assertEquals("ok", res);

     //Testing if bar(Xray, Baz) was called by bar(Alpha, Baz)
     PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(stub).invoke("bar", Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));
     // Mockito's equivalent for a public method: verify(stub, times(1)).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
   }
}
```

Observation : when calling verify methods, we have to pass stub object not actual object because we set expectations on stub object. As I added assert statements to test the method, you don't have to verify on the stub whether it is working properly or not.

**ADDED:** 
I added sysout statements in both public & private 'bar' methods and when I tested again, I see that sysout statement of public bar method is not printed.
It means the above code mocked public method only but not private method.

To mock private 'bar' method, I tried with another way of mocking using MemberMatcher.method which worked perfectly.

```
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class) // we need this
public class FooTest {

@Test
 public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() throws Exception {
     Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
     Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
     alpha.set(new Xray());

     Foo stub = PowerMockito.spy(new Foo());

     PowerMockito.doReturn("ok")
        .when(stub,
                MemberMatcher.method(Foo.class,
                        "bar",
                        Xray.class, Baz.class))
        .withArguments(Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));

     String res = stub.bar(alpha, baz);

     Assert.assertEquals("ok", res);

     //Testing if bar(Xray, Baz) was called by bar(Alpha, Baz)
     PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(stub).invoke("bar", Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));
     // Mockito's equivalent for a public method: verify(stub, times(1)).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
 }

 output : public bar
```

Test method is also passed. Below are foo methods having sysouts.

```
private String bar(Xray xray, Baz baz) {
    System.out.println("private bar");
    return "Xray";
}

public String bar(Alpha alpha, Baz baz) {

    System.out.println("public bar");

    if(alpha.get() instanceof Xray) {
        return bar((Xray)alpha.get(), baz);
    } else if(alpha.get() instanceof Zulu) {
        return bar((Zulu)alpha.get(), baz);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, if I change that to `PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(stub, times(5)).invoke("bar", Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));` it turns out that you are checking how often you call `String res = stub.bar(alpha, baz);` - it doesn't seem to look at `Foo` itself. Which makes sense, as `any()` always returns `void` for as far as I know - so PowerMock has no way of checking the types at runtime - and matches `bar(Alpha, Baz)`.

Comment: Changing it to `Method m = Whitebox.getMethod(Foo.class, Xray.class, Baz.class);` `PowerMockito.doReturn("ok").when(stub, m).withArguments(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));` for `times(5)` just makes it fail with `Wanted but not invoked:
foo.bar(<any>, <any>);
-> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Comment: @Christian,  my first answer did not mock private bar method, Instead it mocked public bar method, I corrected the test method using MemberMatcher.method, Look at detailed explanation in my updated answer.