# PowerMockito doesn't match overloaded method when return types differ

Tags: java, powermock, overloading, private-members, powermockito

This is now part 3 in a [series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32208501/2018047)...

I'm (still) trying to check if `bar(Alpha, Baz)` called `bar(Xray, Baz)` using PowerMockito (`bar(Xray, Baz)` is `private`) - without actually calling the later, given my MCVE class `Foo` below. Note that `bar(Alpha, Baz)` returns nothing, while the other two return `String`, and that I'm aware I [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206838/2018047) maybe test for *that* the Foo works, instead of *how*...

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar(Xray xray, Baz baz) { return "Xray"; }

    private String bar(Zulu zulu, Baz baz) { return "Zulu"; }

    public void bar(Alpha alpha, Baz baz) { // this one returns nothing
        if(alpha.get() instanceof Xray) {
            System.out.println(bar((Xray) alpha.get(), baz));
            return;
        } else if(alpha.get() instanceof Zulu) {
            System.out.println(bar((Zulu)alpha.get(), baz));
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

User kswaughs [solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219738/2018047) for private overloaded methods, when all methods have the same return type. And [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725116/2018047) it was suggested to use the `when()` method with a `Method` object... However, now that I have defined `bar(Alpha, Baz)` to use a different return type form the other methods, all falls apart again:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() throws Exception {
        Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
        Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
        alpha.set(new Xray());

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo stub = PowerMockito.spy(foo);

        Method m = Whitebox.getMethod(Foo.class, "bar", Xray.class, Baz.class);

        PowerMockito.doReturn("ok").when(stub, m);

        stub.bar(alpha, baz); // fails here - even though that then calls stub.bar(Xray, Baz);

        // Testing if bar(Xray, Baz) was called by bar(Alpha, Baz)
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(stub, times(5)).invoke("bar", any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
    }
}
```

The exception in all its beauty:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
'bar' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. The method you are trying to stub is *overloaded*. Make sure you are calling the right overloaded version.
2. Somewhere in your test you are stubbing *final methods*. Sorry, Mockito does not verify/stub final methods.
3. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

    at FooTest.testBar_callsBarWithXray(FooTest.java:31)
```

Using `.withArguments(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class))` doesn't seem to make a difference.

While spot-on, the exception does unfortunately not tell how to make point 1 come true with the setup I have. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are missing the @PrepareForTest(Foo.class) class type anotation

Answer (score 0):

Here, the problem is not with different return types, It is with overloaded methods only. Use  MemberMatcher.method() instead of WhiteBox.getMethod, 
For testing purpose, Added sysout statement at top of the public bar method.

```
public void bar(Alpha alpha, Baz baz) { // this one returns nothing

System.out.println("public bar");

if(alpha.get() instanceof Xray) {
    System.out.println(bar((Xray) alpha.get(), baz));
    return;
} else if(alpha.get() instanceof Zulu) {
    System.out.println(bar((Zulu)alpha.get(), baz));
    return;
} else {
    return;
}
}
```

Below is the test method, PrepareForTest is required for Foo.class when we using MemberMatcher.

```
@Test
 public void testBar_callsBarWithXray() throws Exception {
     Baz baz = new Baz(); //POJOs
     Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
     alpha.set(new Xray());

     Foo stub = PowerMockito.spy(new Foo());

     Method m = MemberMatcher.method(Foo.class,
                "bar",
                Xray.class, Baz.class);

     PowerMockito.doReturn("ok")
        .when(stub, m )
        .withArguments(Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));

     stub.bar(alpha, baz);

     PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(stub, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("bar", Matchers.any(Xray.class), Matchers.any(Baz.class));
     // Mockito's equivalent for a public method: verify(stub, times(1)).bar(any(Xray.class), any(Baz.class));
 }

output is :
public bar
ok
```